# Flask File Uploads to Unique Directory

Tags: python, flask

I've built an application following the file upload process (more or less) along the lines of the Flask file upload documentation found here, https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/.

In this portion of the code, `UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'`, this points to one, single directory where file uploads will live. The problem I'm trying to solve is when I deploy my app to a server there will be multiple, simultaneous users. With a single upload directory, users will collide when they upload files with the same names--a situation that will occur in my app.

What I want to do is create a **unique** temp directory that is **unique** to each browser session. So, user 1 would have their own unique temp directory and user 2 would have their own unique temp directory and so on.

In this case, I *think* there would not be any user collision. Can anyone please suggest how I would create such unique temp directories associated with each browser session in the file upload process? Something along the lines of `UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads/user1_session'`, etc for each unique user?

Comment: Here is an excellent link that would help you in the future when asking questions. [ask] . The summary of the link is basically "The more concise and detailed your question is the better help/answers you will get"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so lacking further information and any sort of view on what your code/program looks like this is the what I would recommend at the moment.

I am relatively new to programming as well so this might not be the best answer. But in my experience you really,really do not want to be creating multiple directories per user/per session. That is a bad idea. This is where databases comes in handy.

Now in regards to your problem the easiest/fastest way to resolve this issue is to look into how password salt and hashing is done.

Just hash and salt your filenames.

Here is a [link](https://pythonprogramming.net/password-hashing-flask-tutorial/) that provides a simple yet through explanation on how it is done.